# $1$-forms on $M$ with values on a Lie group $G$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, fiber-bundles

I'm working on something related to differential geometry though I'm definitely not a geometer myself and I have encountered with the following object. Let $G$ be a Lie group acting on a differential manifold $M$ and for each $x\in M$ put
$$
 D_x = \{ f : T_xM \rightarrow  G : f(0_x) = 1 \text{ and } d_{0_x}f = 0 \}.
$$
Consider now $D=\coprod_{x\in M} D_x$. It seems to me that $D$ *has* to be well-known. Have you guys seen this somewhere?

Comment: As a lifelong geometer, I have to complain that this has nothing to do with differential forms or anything else I’ve worked with. No wedge product, sum, or exterior derivative. And why is it germane that $G$ acts on $M$?

Comment: Can you describe how you come up with such an object?